# How to align text in Smart Forms

Tags: sap-smart-forms

I am trying to center the line INVOICE in a text of Smart Form. I have selected a style which has in paragraph format `C` (center).

How can I do this?

My SAP is 7.02.
Please help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: _> My SAP is 7.02_ --> What is SAP 7.02? And are we talking about _Smart Forms_ from SAPUI5? Or [SAP Smart Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-smart-forms)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I wanted to center align a text (3 lines) in a text element. Now the default editor is ms word but we cannot do sth. I have chosen a style with a center (C) option in paragraph but I could not find where to put it. Finally I found that I have to put the C in the old editor in the place of the *. Thanks for your concern